# ¿Sass no compila las variables insertadas en :root?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

Estoy trabajando con `sass` y `Bulma.css`, entonces en mi hoja customizada
`_custom.scss` se encuentra las siguientes variables($):

```
  //sass variables
  $color-1: #12D3CF;
  $color-2: #1F2937;
  $color-title-true: #1F2937;
  $color-title-false: #e5e7eb;
  $color-text-true: #6b7280;
  $color-text-false: #d1d5db;
  $color-border-light: #E5E7EB;
```

En mi hoja `style.scss`(mi hoja principal):

```
@use "custom" as *;
:root {
--color-primary: $color-1;
--color-second: $color-2;
--color-title-true: $color-title-true;
--color-title-false: $color-title-false;
--color-text-true: $color-text-true;
--color-text-false: $color-text-false;
--color-border-light: $color-border-light;
}
.button:active{
  border-color: $color-1;
}
```

Y cuando compilo a `css`, hoja `style.css` salen las siguientes variables:

```
:root {
--color-primary: $color-1;
--color-second: $color-2;
--color-title-true: $color-title-true;
--color-title-false: $color-title-false;
--color-text-true: $color-text-true;
--color-text-false: $color-text-false;
--color-border-light: $color-border-light;
}
.button:active{
  border-color: #12D3CF;
}
```

Como pueden notar solo dentro de :root las variables no son reconocidas.

**¿Tiene alguna explicación de por que no son reconocidas en :root?.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para utilizar tus variables SASS en el `:root` del CSS debes declarar la variable usando [Interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation), de esta forma: `#{$variable}`.

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
//sass variables
$color-1: #12D3CF;
$color-2: #1F2937;
$color-title-true: #1F2937;
$color-title-false: #e5e7eb;
$color-text-true: #6b7280;
$color-text-false: #d1d5db;
$color-border-light: #E5E7EB;

:root {
--color-primary: #{$color-1};
--color-second: #{$color-2};
--color-title-true: #{$color-title-true};
--color-title-false: #{$color-title-false};
--color-text-true: #{$color-text-true};
--color-text-false: #{$color-text-false};
--color-border-light: #{$color-border-light};
}

.button:active{
  border-color: $color-1;
}
```

---

Aquí tienes un [ejemplo reproducible](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/f78c2141e91ff59e2254e710d235c98b)

Answer (score 0):

no conozco Bulma pero te fijate si te funciona de esta manera:

```
:root {
--color-primary: variables.$color-1;
--color-second: variables.$color-2;
```